# Can we show both up votes and downvotes by default?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, down-votes, up-votes

Isn't there a way to see both upvotes and downvotes on a question at the question?

Isn't the default to add the thumbs up and minus the thumbs down and then the user has this number that represents sort of the average vote?

Can the default change to that average vote number and also at the same time, how many voted up and how many voted down. That would give one looking for the answer better insight into what might be the correct answer or what might be an answer  that is more argumentative.

The way it is by default(at least it is on mine), 10 people could love the answer and 10 people could hate it and the rating would show 0 so those looking for answers might not know they're  in a war zone so to speak.-metta

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this feature is implemented as  a "privilege" available to "established users" -- see [Help Center > Privileges > Established User](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user)

I don't know why it isn't available to all users; one reason may be to reduce the complexity of the user interface seen by new users.

I don't think we can persuade Stack Exchange to change this (or any) functionality.

Can you identify some specific answer[s], which have this kind of "voting war" happening? I ask because I wonder whether there's some other way, to clarify that sort of answer for new users.

Comment: By voting war I mean some vote up, some vote down and some do neither.

Comment: I think I know what you mean: i.e. lots of up-votes and lots of down-votes on the same answer. But do you have an example or two, of such an answer, in mind? Because, I wonder whether a comment on that answer, or an edit, might make the answer any clearer.

Comment: Right, ok. That shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Gosh, I never thought I would make it to that point! Wow, on some site I can finally see both vote counts! Only took years, ironically on Buddhism. Amazing.

Comment: @UUU Would you "accept" this answer? Otherwise it will be "bumped to the homepage by Community♦" again and again, forever.

Comment: @ChrisW The voting here is almost as random, reactive and surprising as the  the voting in the United States. Rather than voting maybe we should just pick the correct answers. If we have to "vote" on what is the truth then we are far from knowing what the truth is.

Comment: @UUU I hope that people do pick whatever they can that's useful from the answers. But anyway I can't change the way in which the software (web site) implements voting, and provides a UI for it.

Comment: @ChrisW Yeah. I'm just talking you know. We

Comment: @ChrisW  Oh yes, I know that but that doesn't mean we can't ponder such things, does it? Maybe someday we will figure out a solution that the web site leaders will like. Who knows :)